# How to include a Muse file in a Wordpress theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress, muse

I've designed header in Adobe Muse and I want to include it on my wordpress theme. I tried to use a php include statement like so within the header.php file:

```
<?php
chdir('pages');
set_include_path('pages');
include 'index.html';
?>
```

The code calls the correct file but none of the images or css is loading. When I look at the debugging console it shows that the code is not calling the correct path for these images and css. It's looking in the root directory instead of the pages directory. How can I get the index.html file to run with the correct working directory?